# Maximizing Wisdom-based ranged attacks per round

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization

Is there any combination of abilities that allow one to make multiple ranged attacks per turn, every turn, that are Wisdom-based?

Examples of the sort of things I have in mind:

- Some way to use Wisdom with ranged weapon attacks that is compatible with Extra Attack and/or two-weapon fighting
- Some way to get *eldritch blast* to use Wisdom
- Some other cantrip that includes multiple attacks, and uses Wisdom

If there are multiple approaches, the one which achieves the greatest number of “hits” (even if it does less damage) is ideal for my purposes. If there are multiple approaches to getting the same number of attacks, then I’ll likely favor whichever does so at the earliest level, though depending on the details other considerations (such as how many resources are dedicated to this) may win out.

The only option I am aware of for this is *magic stone*, but that has some awkward impediments:

- You need a bonus action to set it up
- It’s not clear that throwing a *magic stone* is compatible with Extra Attack, and it probably isn’t compatible with two-weapon fighting
- Using a sling is on better ground with respect to Extra Attack, but definitely cannot achieve two-weapon fighting. Some still argue it cannot work with Extra Attack, too.

Feats, variant human, and various *Tasha’s* alternate or optional features are allowed. *Unearthed Arcana* content is allowed so long as it hasn’t been superceded by official publications, but I would prefer non-*UA* content. Regardless, please note the source of all materials going into achieving the build.

Comment: Are there any other preferences you have(secondarily a caster? etc.) I've got an idea, but more info would help me.

Comment: @NautArch My initial plan was to use it to trigger Gathering Swarm more, but then it was pointed out that Gathering Swarm has a once per turn limitation anyway. Crusher is a similar effect without that limitation, but it’s bludgeoning-damage only, which means answers to this question may or may not actually help with that (but that wasn’t initially part of the question). Ultimately, this is (now, given that Gathering Swarm is out) more of a “I need to know what my options are so I can build around it” than it is a “I have a build in mind that needs more attacks,” so I’m pretty open.

Comment: Are you considering also 1st level spells or only cantrips?

Comment: @Eddymage If it worked all day or long enough that I could use it in every combat or something, sure. If I need a 1st-level spell slot for every round in which I want to make multiple attacks, then no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Magic Stone should work with Extra Attack

There's a [Crawford tweet](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/752595441477312512?lang=en), if that's your jam, stating that:

> Magic stone works with a feature that benefits attacks in general or ranged attacks, but not weapon attacks.

It's also somewhat evident from the design of the spell: most damaging cantrips increase their damage at 5th, 11th and 17th level. That this one doesn't implies that its scaling comes through features such as Extra Attack.

### Or, Be a Stars Druid

The Circle of Stars found in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything offers the following option:

> As a bonus action, you can expend a use of your Wild Shape feature to take on a starry form... The form lasts for 10 minutes. It ends early if you dismiss it (no action required), are incapacitated, die, or use this feature again.
>
> **Archer**. A constellation of an archer appears on you. When you activate this form, and as a bonus action on your subsequent turns while it lasts, you can make a ranged spell attack, hurling a luminous arrow that targets one creature within 60 feet of you. On a hit, the attack deals radiant damage equal to 1d8 + your Wisdom modifier.

There are plenty of ways to make a Wisdom-based ranged attack as an action, so in Archer form you can make two Wisdom-based ranged attacks on each of your turns. It's not infinite, but with two uses of Wild Shape per short rest, you can be spamming this in most combats.

Comment: @NautArch: One as a bonus action and one as an action (e.g. Produce Flame). That's two per turn.

Comment: Missed that, but you already had my upvote :)

Answer (score 7):

### You'll want Magic Stone

As you've noted, there are a lot of limitations here and not many options that can be fulfilled with them. Because of that, *magic stone* really becomes your primary tool, and this is why.

#### TWF Ranged

Your options here are really limited in the dagger, light hammer, and hand axe. At max, those are d6+modifier and are limited to 60' range. These are functionally equivalent to *magic stone*, but without the bonus action use to create them.

Dual Wielding

Picking up the Dual Wielder feat will give you some more options in terms of ranged weapons, but you still aren't really improving upon *magic stone* by all that much - especially if you are investing in WIS over DEX or STR.

*Magic Stone* also won't work with this 'out of the box'. However, it's a reasonable ask (please see below about concerns) and it can also be mitigate through Dual Wielder. However, I don't think that's even really necessary as your bonus action will be spent casting the stones and you'd likely be better off with another option for your bonus action.

#### Extra Attack

Options under this area become a bit more with the introduction of bows/crossbows. However, there aren't any published methods to achieve using those weapons with a different ability score.

That brings us back to the option we do have for throwing more than one thing with wisdom, and that's *magic stone*.

#### The case for slings

The sling will increase your total range by 60', but disadvantage will start past 30' - which is worse than *magic stone.* You can always carry a sling if you need it, but odds are you'll have better options for that sort of distance past 60'.

### Moving beyond the second attack

At this point, all signs point to *magic stone* for your wisdom-based ranged attacks. However, that's just one piece of your arsenal as a character. You can fill in with other classes and just use a dip for the cantrip, or even magic initiate via v.human to start.

Finding other classes that can supplement and give you some more fun options, like possibly the kensei monk, could be a way to get the extra attacks, use your boosted WIS and additional options during play.

### Magic Stone concerns

I see you have concerns about using *magic stone* for either Extra Attack or TWF. They are just stones and you can are assumed to be naturally 'loading' when attacking with ranged weapons that don't have the loading property. Given they don't have that property, I see no issue there.

As for TWF, that may be a bigger issue because they aren't light, but you could pick up Dual Wielder to bypass that.

There is also the concern that the stone is not a melee weapon. That will be up to the DM, but I'd say it is.

However, as a DM, I don't see any issues in allowing a build like this. You're making some sacrifices to do it in needing a bonus action for 3 rocks, and granting them the light property I don't foresee having an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123427/discussion-between-nautarch-and-kryan).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123846/discussion-between-nautarch-and-smbailey).